# Play video file (mp4 file) from an URL in swift 2 with xCode 7.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I try to play an mp4 file from an URL. 
Below is code:

```
func playVideo(url: NSURL){
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        player.play()
    }
```

And I've called it in viewDidAppear function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let fileURL = NSURL(string: "http://myserveraddress:8080/music/test.mp4")!
    playVideo(fileURL)

}
```

But it's not working. The result as the picture. Please check with me.

[image]
Thanks you so much

Answer (score 8):

have you added the relevant entries to the info.ptlist?

IOS will require you to add an entry to your app's info.ptlist in order to stream  videos from URLS (among other things), this will prevent your app from blocking streams of data that are not considered secure as they are not encrypted. Keep in mind that if you publish the app in the AppStore Apple will probably ask you to add the needed keys to the info.ptlist so that you only allow traffic from trusted URLs, rather than every single connection.

For debugging, you can add the dictionary key "App Transport Security Settings" with "Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES". As follows:

[image: App transport security settings]

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Comment: hi,i have already added this to my plist but still its showing the same as in the image.

Comment: Can you confirm that the url you are using can be used for streaming your video?

Comment: I checked all the above, I added this to the info.plist file, I also checked the url if its working on a browser, but its not working on the AVPlayer, any help pls ??