# Embedded AVPlayer is not playing video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, app-transport-security, embedded-video

I am trying to **embed video player** using **Swift**. When I run the app, I can see the video player but video is not playing. Could you check out any missing point, please? Thanks in advance.

```
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var player: AVPlayer?

if let videoLink = newLaunch.videoLinks where newLaunch.videoLinks!.count > 0{

    let videoUrl = videoLink[0]
    let streamingURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl)
    player = AVPlayer(URL: streamingURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.videoContainerView.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.videoContainerView.bounds
    player!.play()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check this-> instead of adding playercontroller as childcontroller.. present/push it. Is is working now?. If yes, then atleast we comes to know that.. this is due to adding childviewcontroller otherwise, there is some other problem with AVPlayer.

Comment: @Mehul, I think so. I will try it out.

Comment: Also, check by debugging that fileurlpath, that you used is proper or not. sometimes, path using fileurlpath makes problem, so try other way too

Comment: @MehulThakkar, I already check file url path and I can see file path receiving from server.

Comment: If you are using server url.. then never use fileURLWithPath, Got the problem.. use urlWithString for server url. fileURLWithPath is for local urls. Now it will work. Try. I am 100% sure that, this url have made the problem, am i right?

Comment: @Mehul, I got this from server. "> Video Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao2fdQUgvq4" . It returns string value. I think it's because of ChildViewController.

Comment: Have you try with AVPlayerLayer?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya, yes. When I tried with AVPlayerLayer, it didn't show even video player.

Comment: @ZinMarHtet Have you read my answer?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya, Hello, yes, I saw it just now. I will try it out later coz I'm working on other task now. Thank you so much for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way apart from `UIWebView` to play youtube video inside iOS application. 
Also you can redirect to youtube application by passing your video url.So youtube application will handle rest of the things.

You can read the guidelines of YouTube section 2 point 10 :https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=en

You can use youtube player : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#installation

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I used [Swift Youtube Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) to embed video. It's super easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IOS are you using? it looks like this might be related to Apple's new [transport layer security enhancements](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/).

You need to enable your app to allow streaming video from that particular domain. You can alternatively bypass the transport layer security for while you develop your app.

Check out this thread for how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305505/5229157

**Also**, you might want to use a different url constructor for streaming your file:

```
let videoUrl = videoLink[0]
let streamingURL = NSURL(string: videoUrl) //- assuming videoLink is of type [String]
player = AVPlayer(URL: streamingURL)
```

**Edit**:

Try the following code:

```
let videoUrl = videoLink[0]
let streamingURL = NSURL(string: videoUrl)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = AVPlayer(URL: streamingURL)
self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
    self.playerController.player?.play()
}
```

Comment: I'm using iOS 8.1. In info.plist, I set "Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES". And I tried by using NSURL(string: videoUrl) too, but result is same. Video is still not playing.

Comment: I edited my answer, try that approach from your view controller. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, still not playing video.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I just realized that i missed a line _playerController.player = AVPlayer(URL: streamingURL)_, I updated the code block

Comment: In my code, I embedded playerController inside of videoContainerView. So beside of your code, I added two lines of code for adding subview into videoContainerView. But result is no different.

Answer (score -1):

you can add the AVPlayer as a layer on the view:

```
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init....

playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
float x = size.width/2.0-187.0;
float y = size.height/2.0 - 125.0;

playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 474, 320);
[playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player play];
```